Mapping through an object
I'm coding using javascript & react. I have an object named "rates" I'm trying to map through:
{
    "M": {
        "lab": {
            "S": "50%"
        },
        "dme": {
            "S": "75%"
        },
        "therapy": {
            "S": "80%"
        },
        "radio": {
            "S": "85%"
        },
        "drugs": {
            "S": "100%"
        }
    }
}

Here's how I'm mapping through it:
const rateList = rates.M.map(
              (rate) => {
                return {
                  "DME": {
                    S: rates.M.dme.S,
                  },
                  "Lab": {
                    S: rates.M.lab.S,
                  },
                  "Drugs": {
                    S: rates.M.drugs.S,
                  },
                  "Radio": {
                    S: rates.M.radio.S,
                  },
                  "Therapy": {
                    S: rates.M.therapy.S,
                  },
                };
              },
            );


I keep on getting error "rates.M.map is not a function". I'm assuming because "rates" is not an array but an object.
How should I remap? So the values from the object is displayed to its corresponding labels?
I appreciate your guidance!

"I'm assuming because "rates" is not an array but an object" - yes. Just drop the rates.M.map((rate) => { return part, simply assign the new object to rateList?

Btw you can probably simplify "DME": { S: rates.M.dme.S }, to just "DME": rates.M.dme,

Hi :). Can you clarify what you mean by assign the new object to rate List?

Map is mean to use for mapping arrays, not objects

I mean const rateList = { "DME": …, … };. Unless, of course, you actually want a list, i.e. an array.

Bergi, thank you for your response. The only thing is rateList is not the one with the API data, "rates" is. Or are you saying something like this will work: const rateList = { "DME": rates.M.dme, "Lab": rates.M.lab, ... } ? Will that work to display/"return" the values on my UI?

Map is an Array method. Are you trying to change the key tp uppercase, @PhuongHoang68?

The Alpha, I'm trying to display the values from from the object "rates" onto my UI

@PhuongHoang68 can you post what you want the final result to look like?

If you are trying to get the rates displayed in the DOM, you can just use a couple of for in loops. What exactly you put inside the for in loops of course depends on what your UI looks like.
But this code snippet is an example of walking through your rates data structure.


rates = {
    "M": {
        "lab": {
            "S": "50%"
        },
        "dme": {
            "S": "75%"
        },
        "therapy": {
            "S": "80%"
        },
        "radio": {
            "S": "85%"
        },
        "drugs": {
            "S": "100%"
        }
    }
}


displayRates( )

function displayRates( ) {
  let tableSpan = document.querySelector( "#RatesContainerID span" )
  let tableBody = document.querySelector( "#RatesContainerID tbody" )
  let spanHtml = ""
  let tBodyHtml = ""

  // Work through sections (only M in the example data)
  for( let section in rates ) {
    spanHtml = section

    // Next add all the data rows
    for( let item in rates[section] ) {
      // Capitalize the fisrt character
      let itemName = item.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)

      tBodyHtml += `<tr> <td>${itemName}</td> <td>${rates[section][item].S}</td> </tr>`
    }
  }

  tableSpan.innerHTML = spanHtml
  tableBody.innerHTML = tBodyHtml
}
table {
  border: solid 2px gray;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  border-spacing: unset;
}
thead {
  /* background-color: cyan; */
}
tr {
  border: solid 1px maroon;
}
th {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
th, td {
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 4px;
  text-align: start;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: end;
}
<div id="RatesContainerID">
  <table>
    <span>X</span>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th> <th>S</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>example</td>  <td>%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




There's no mention of displaying in the from in the original question. It has to do with the map function itself.

@Phix In the original post he says "So the values from the object is displayed to its corresponding labels". Then in a comment he clarifies saying "I'm trying to display the values from from the object "rates" onto my UI". He was trying to use map function, which obviously was the wrong way to process the object.

That doesn't matter. Adding code to display in a table is reaching at best. Yea, using map isn't correct here, they could use object.entries and map over that, etc. I'm saying your answer isn't addressing the problem as it sits.

Not to mention this isn't a react-y way to do it.
